# Clone a umbraco project using GitHub Desktop

Tags: umbraco

I´ve a project in github and i did clone it to a different machine, but i´m geting this error: Umbraco cannot start. A connection string is configured but the Umbraco cannot connect to the database

Comment: and i´m getting this error: Server Error in '/' Application. Line 178:        <add assembly="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder" />

Comment: Instead of adding a comment, you should just edit the question. Be sure to put code/errors in  backticks for improved readability.

Answer (score 1):

First things first. Did you check for the connections string properties? Is the clone with the right credentials?

Regarding the ModelsBuilder assembly, i'm guessing that you need to get the UmbracoModelsBuilder dll from the original project and copy into the bin output from the new one. Until you pass this assembly and connection string in order to get umbraco started, you can't configure the way the umbracoModels builder behaviour.

Comment: ok! I did copy the dll file, and the erro change, now is: Could not load all types from "Umbraco.Core

Comment: sounds like corrupt files.... or wrong versions. In this new "machine" are you sure that you have installed all the requirements? .net framework in right version? Can you try to re-install all the nuget packages on this new solution?